# Horizontal menu in WP default theme

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm setting up a simple webpage using Wordpress. You can watch it at www.unistore.se. How can I include a horizontal menu just below the header? I would like to be able to create new links in the menu with the "New page"-function in the wordpress admin.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the page template for this.

Answer (score 0):

From a glance at your site, it looks like you may have already figured this out, but just in case - to edit your page template go to header.php in the theme folder and put this function under the < h1 > displaying the title:

```
<?php wp_list_pages(); ?>
```

You can then wrap that function in a div and style the list to appear horizontally.

Alternate solution:
I haven't tried this, but there is a plugin for creating menus in WordPress - here's a link:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allwebmenus-wordpress-menu-plugin/

Or just search for 'menu' in http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/